# Rails4 Should I prevent multiple URIs indicate the same action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose you have `UsersController` and routes are configured in `config/routes.rb` as the followings.

```
root 'users#index' # root should list all users
resources :users
```

Then `rake routes` shows

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action    
        root GET    /                         users#index       
       users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
       users POST   /users(.:format)          users#create      
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new         
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit        
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show        
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update      
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update      
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

There are a couple of URIs indicating same `users#index` action.
Should I prevent this kind of URI duplication or should I let them alone for me to follow Rails' default convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are a couple of URIs indicating same users#index action. There are a couple of URIs indicating same users#index action.

Well, that's what you've specified by creating the `users` resource **and** then pointing the root path to `users#index`. If you don't want this behavior, you can remove the default index action from the resource.

```
resources :users, except: [:index]
```

Note that with this place, you can no longer refer to the index path via the traditional URL helpers. Personally I wouldn't be concerned with this and just let the URL duplication exist.

Comment: @5t111111 If you're not satisfied with the answer, please provide more information and I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

For `root` it's okay--this is typical and it's just redirecting to the users resource.